# Solving $\ln\left(\frac{1}{x-2}\right)=\frac{1+2e^x}{e^x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

Here's the question I came across, they're inverses in this case, but I imagine that there is a way to do that without them being inverses.

$$\ln\left(\frac{1}{x-2}\right)=\frac{1+2e^x}{e^x}$$

Comment: Equations like this are often impossible to solve without getting extremely lucky. Is there a reason you expect a nice solution?

Comment: I looked at it graphically and there was a solution( albeit not nice) but I'm not sure how to get to that same solution algebraeically

Comment: You probably can't. Mathematica couldn't solve this but gave the approximation $2.1200282389876412295$

Answer (score 2):

We're trying to solve the following equation for x:
$$\log\left(\frac{1}{x-2}\right) = \frac{1+2e^x}{e^x}$$
As you pointed out, these expressions are inverses of each other. By substituting one side into the other, we can observe that
$$x = \log\left(\frac{1}{x-2}\right)$$
(i.e. $x$ equals $y$ at the intersection of the graphs of these functions).
From this position we can take the exponential of both sides and multiply by the denominator to get:
$$(x-2)e^{x}=1$$
Unless you have some prior experience with these sorts of problems, this looks equally hopeless. The key is to introduce the [Lambert W-Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) also known as [Product Log](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) (ProductLog [in Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProductLog.html)). The key property of this function is that:
$$W(x)e^{W(x)} = x$$
We can get our prior equation into this form by multiplying both sides by $e^{-2}$
$$(x-2)e^{x-2}=\frac{1}{e^2}$$
Implying, using our new function,
$$x-2 = W\left(\frac{1}{e^2}\right)$$
Giving us our final expression for $x$:
$$x = 2 + W\left(\frac{1}{e^2}\right)$$
WolframAlpha is [happy to evaluate this for you](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2+%2B+ProductLog%281%2Fe%5E2%29) and yields the result $x\approx 2.12003$, or you can use infinite series available at the previously linked resources to compute it on your own with some code. For example:
$$x = 2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-n)^{n-1}}{n!}e^{-2n}$$

```
import math

def W(x):
    return sum( [ x**n * (-n)**(n-1) / (math.factorial(n)) for n in range(1,100)] )

x = 2 + W(math.e ** -2)
print(x)
```

Which will print 2.1200282389876413